# nginx on vagrant: request not reaching virtual host/server block

Tags: nginx, vagrant, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, portforwarding

I'm running an instance of nginx on a vagrant setup currently.  I'm trying to have my nginx run two different URLs dev.v1.example.com and dev.v2.example.com by setting up virtual hosting/server blocks for them

The vagrant port forwarding works fine and I can reach the nginx from my host machine

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8980
```

So of course that means for me to access them on a browser on the host machine I'd have to type in dev.v1.example.com:8980 for example

My nginx.conf on the guest is your standard default nginx.conf

```
    # For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

I have the following file at conf.d/vhost.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.v1.example.com;
    root   /vagrant/dev_v1;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.v2.example.com;
    root   /vagrant/dev_v2;
}
```

Whenever I request dev.v1.example.com:8980 or dev.v2.example.com:8980 from the host I **never** hit the server block and always get the default nginx start page which is what the default server block points to. It is  never able to display the content for each specific server name in their respective root folders, but I would think the server block gets hit with the requests given how it's configured.

I've tried changing the listen ports in the vhost.conf to 8980 as well and it doesn't work along with changing the server name to append the 8980 port which always doesn't change anything, and I can see the 'Host' header in the requests I'm making is dev.v1.example.com:8980 and that's also what comes up in the nginx logs in the vagrant guest

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a reverse proxy on your host with two upstream :

```js
upstream dev1__upstream {
   server 192.168.33.2:80;
   keepalive 64;
   }
upstream dev2__upstream {
   server 192.168.33.3:80;
   keepalive 64;
   }
```

and simply create vhost with a proxy pass :

```js
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  dev1.local;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/dev1.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/dev2.error.log;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://dev1__upstream;
    }
}
```